# Align more_vert button on the right side in Angular-material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular7

How can I have the more_vert button align on the right side in the header?
I'm using Angular 7 and Material UI.

```
 <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z10">
<span>
  <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
  Derek Zoolander's Center for Models Who Can't Find Love
</span>
<button mat-icon-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key was to have `<span class="example-spacer"></span>` between your title `<span>` and the "*more_vert*" `mat-icon`.

**complete HTML**:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z10">

  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
    <span>
      Derek Zoolander's Center for...
    </span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-icon-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
      <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="expand menu">more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>

</mat-toolbar>
```

you can check [working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyzi7s)...

Comment: I needed <mat-toolbar-row>
thanks